# MS SQL Layer - Losing LineStrings (Polyline) from SQL Server to QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server, connection

I have a table called **[gfts].[Shapes]** which contains a primary key **shape_id** and a geography data type **GEOM**. When I query the table in SQL Server I get the following Spatial Results:

[image]

However, when I add an MS SQL Layer in QGIS I only have a few of the LineStrings (PolyLines). Whats the issue here. The data seems to be leaking!

[image]

Comment: you may have an invalid linestring in there that SQL Server doesn't care about but QGIS does.  Try updating the shape in SQL Server using shape.MakeValid() and see if that helps